# Progress-bar Div style

Tags: css, progress-bar

There is a progress-bar and works fine but I have an issue on styling part. As you can see on the image,  I want right side of progressing as on the image. I am not that good on the css. If there is a hero to explain to me how I could style it, I would be really happy about it.

I appreciate your effort :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOmSM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at demo

HTML

```
<div class="progress" >
  <div style="width: 50%;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.progress { background: #e3e887; text-align: left; font-size: 0; }
.progress > div { display: inline-block; height: 88px; position: relative; background: linear-gradient(to right, #e21e2c 0%, #cac511 100%); overflow: hidden; }
.progress > div:before { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; content: ''; width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 44px solid #e3e887; border-left: 44px solid transparent; }
.progress > div:after { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; content: ''; width: 0; height: 0; border-bottom: 44px solid #e3e887; border-left: 44px solid transparent; }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/2rtub73n/)

Comment: You asked to explain... Triangles are made with pseudo-elements. You can easily find this technique in the interner, even web-tool to make them. Gradient is self explanatory.

Comment: Thank you @IIya it works perfectly :) I will search your tips.